# Axios catch error only shows Network Error instead of message from server

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to build a SPA project with Vuejs and using .NET WebAPI as backend.

When I use Axios to send request to the WebAPI, if there is an error on the server side, in the catch, I only get 'Error: NetWork Error', but in Fiddler, I can see the real message returned from server: eg: 406 'version not allowed blablab'.

```
axios.get("My_WebAPI_IURL")  
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Promise.reject(error)
    })
```

Also in console, there is an error message of CORS

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://blablabla' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

But I've already configured on the WebAPI to allow CORS, normally all the endpoints work correctly, I only have this CORS error message when the server returns an error response.

I searched online, and tried error.reponse, but it is always Undefined.

Where is the problem?

This is the code in WebAPI to enable CORS

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors();
```